# Spring Integration: Getting Exception on refreshing application context 2nd time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am refreshing the application context in a spring integration project which consists of various gateways and service activators. Refreshing works fine for the first time, but getting this exception on subsequent refreshes (done after considerable intervals).

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contextReload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String contextReload() throws Exception {
    LOG.info(" Reloading Application Context");
    refreshAsync(); 
    return "responseOK";
}

private void refreshAsync() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(REFRESH_WAIT_TIME_MILLIS); //This fixed the issue
                getContextService().refresh();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error in refreshing context: ", e);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

ApplicationContextService

```
public synchronized void refresh(){
    /*Refresh from top to bottom such that child context beans 
     * have new parent bean reference*/
    while(!appContexts.isEmpty()){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = (ConfigurableApplicationContext)appContexts.pop();
        LOG.info("Refreshing context: "+ctx);
        ctx.refresh();
        LOG.info("Finished refreshing context: "+ctx);
    }
    LOG.info("Context refresh complete!");
}
```

Exception Logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:148)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:86)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:326)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:919)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any pointers as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Going by the first line of the exception, it would appear that you are creating a new context before all of the beans from the previous context have been destroyed. It would be good to show *how* you are refreshing the context. My guess at why the old context hasn't been destroyed is that there are probably threads still running, which are maintaining references to beans from the previous context. These may be your own threads, but I would expect it to be just as likely that they are async processing threads from within Spring Integration.

Answer (score 1):

You must wait until the Destruction of every old singletons is done.

The detach was not clean. Increase the logging output of the class `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` to see what bean has not been destructed.

You also can call

```
  @Component
  public class MyStopApp implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> (...
  @Autowired
  DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry registry;

  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextClosedEvent event){
     registry.destroySingletons();
  }
```

Comment: I got the reason. This is a spring mvc application, I was invoking context refresh in another thread, and returning from controller without waiting for refresh to finish. The exception occurred when the refresh thread was in the process of refreshing and the controller thread was returning, when the controller returned, a web filter was trying to access the particular bean, hence the exception. I just made the refresh thread sleep for 2 seconds before starting refresh, in this time the tomcat controller thread could complete the http request flow.

Comment: Ok, please do not write this in a comment, write it in a Answer to your very own question.